# [PHP][SLIM] move_uploaded_file never ends with larger files in Hosting24

Tags: php, cpanel, slim

I have a question.
I'm trying to upload files to a server, this server is hosted by 'Hosting24', i don't know if that matters, anyway, if I try to move files larger than 70mb It never ends to load and never send a response, my server config is okay, it has these values: `{"post_max_size":"512M","memory_limit":"1024M"}`

I has tryed with $_FILES and ftp transfer and it doesnt works, it never ends of load.
I'm using Slim framework and this is the function:

```
public function testCode($request, $response, $args)
{
    $data = $request->getParsedBody();
    $uploadedFiles = $request->getUploadedFiles();
    //here take files

    $uploadedFile = $uploadedFiles['file_user'];
    $nameC = $data['nombre_curso'];
    //here set path
    $path = "../../scorm/temp/" . $nameC . '/';
    //Creating folders
    if (!@mkdir($path, 0777, true)) {
        $error = error_get_last();
        echo $error['message'];
    }
    $file_name = $uploadedFile->getClientFilename();
    $array = explode(".", $file_name);
    
    $ext = $array[1];
    //if is a zip file
    if ($ext == 'zip') {
        $location = $path . "/" . $file_name;
        //here move the uploaded file to my selected directory
        if (move_uploaded_file($uploadedFile->file, $location)) {
            $obj = (object) array("response" => 'works', 'post_max_size' => ini_get('post_max_size'), 'memory_limit' => ini_get('memory_limit'));
            $response->withStatus(200);
            $response->getBody()->write(json_encode($obj));
            return $response;                
        } else {
            $error = error_get_last();
            echo $error['message'] . " it couldn't be moved";
        }
    } else {
        echo "no zip";
    }

}
```

Comment: Have you checked to see if the host has a cap on uploads? A lot of the cheap hosts will limit it and you need to change it in cPanel or contact them

Comment: A tip, do not use echo in Slim. Use the $response object instead. Then try it again.

Comment: @hurnhu {"post_max_size":"512M","memory_limit":"1024M"} that's my config server of upload file.

Comment: @odan I has tryed remove 'echo's but it keeps not wotking

Comment: Ok fine, 70 MB upload is quite a lot. Normally you should not upload more than 8 or 10 MB over HTTP/S. Regardless of the configuration of your server, what is the maximum allowed by your webshoster? What does the support say about it?